# Methods to calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 - w e^{-it}}\,dt$ disagree

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to evaluate the integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1 - w e^{-it}}\,dt$$

where $w \in \mathbb{C}$, $|w|\ne1$.

Using antiderivatives I get:

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{1 - w e^{-it}}\,dt &= -i \int \frac{1}{u}\,du\\\\& = -i \log(u)\\\\& = -i \log(w - e^{it})
\end{align}$$

where $u = e^{it} - w$.  So, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1 - w e^{-it}} \,dt&= -i (\log(w - e^{2i\pi}) - \log(w - e^{0i}))\\\\
&= -i (\log(w - 1) - \log(w - 1))\\\\
& = -i \log\left(\frac{w - 1}{w - 1}\right)\\\\
& = -i \log(1) \\\\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

But with a contour integral I get:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1 - w e^{-it}}\,dt &= \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{z}{z - w} \frac{1}{iz}\,dz\\\\
& = \frac{1}{i}\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{z - w}\,dz
\end{align}$$

This agrees with my antiderivative above if $|w| > 1$ since then the function is holomorphic in the unit circle (so its contour integral is just $0$), but if $|w| < 1$ there's a simple pole at $z = w$ so this should give $2 \pi$.

Obviously $2 \pi \neq 0$ so I made a mistake somewhere.  Which is correct, and what's the mistake I made in the wrong method?

Comment: The logarithm is multivalued.

Comment: (+1) for the question.

Comment: Why do you expect the same result for all values of $w$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few way to evaluate the integral given by

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac1{1-we^{-it}}\,dt\tag1$$

where $|w|\ne1$.

> NOTE:  While the integral diverges when $|w|=1$, its Cauchy Principal Value exists.

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$: Use of Cauchy's Integral Theorem**

Perhaps the most efficient way to proceed is to let $z=e^{it}$ in $(1)$.  Then, Cauchy's Integral Theorem guarantees that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{1-w/z}\frac1{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac1i \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z-w}\,dz\\\\
&=\begin{cases}2\pi&,|w|<1\\\\0&,|w|>1\tag2
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

And we are done.

---

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$: Use of the complex logarithm**

If we wish to proceed along an analogous line as in the OP, then we must be careful to define the complex logarithm appropriately.  First, we can assume that $w$ is real and non-negative without loss of generality.

To see this, note that the integrand in $(1)$ is $2\pi$-periodic.  Accordingly, we can write

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{\arg(w)}^{\arg(w)+2\pi}\frac1{1-we^{-it}}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{it}-|w|}\,dt
\end{align}$$

---

Next, we cut the $z$ plane from $|w|$ to the point at infinity along the positive real axis, then choose the branch for which

$$0\le \arg\left(e^{it}-|w|\right)<2\pi$$

With this choice of branch cut we see that the complex logarithm, $\log(z-|w|)$, is holomorphic for $|z|<|w|$.  And inasmuch as $|e^{it}|=1$, we can write for $|w|>1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{it}-|w|}\,dt&=\left.\left(\log\left(e^{it}-|w|\right)\right)\right|_0^{2\pi}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

---

But when $|z|>|w|$, the complex logarithm, $\log(z-w)$, is discontinuous across the branch cut with $\log(e^{i2\pi^-}-|w|)-\log(e^{i0^+}-|w|)=i2\pi$.  Inasmuch as $|e^{it}|=1$, we can write for $|w|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{it}}{e^{it}-|w|}\,dt&=\left.\left(\log\left(e^{it}-|w|\right)\right)\right|_{0^+}^{2\pi^-}\\\\
&=i2\pi
\end{align}$$

We conclude, therefore, that

$$\begin{align}
I&=\begin{cases}2\pi&,|w|<1\\\\0&,|w|>1
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

which agrees with the result in $(2)$.

Comment: Very nice!  So what is the story with the principal value?  We integrate through a pole and therefore take a small semicircle around it?  If so, why does the integral diverge?

Comment: @mjw If you deform the contour as you described, the result is the Cauchy Principal Value.  However, if you try and integrate through the pole, the result is a divergent integral.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: @mjw You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @mjw And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, this is very enlightening

Comment: @JayLemmon You're welcome.  Much appreciated!  And please to see that you found it useful.